# Android FacebookSdk Login Button: there's no button label

Tags: android, facebook

I am facing troubles adding a FacebookLogin button in my layout.

It has a strange behaviour: as I add it, I can see the blue button, the logo, but no text is shown on the button.

[image: Emulator screen (same behaviour on a Nexus 5)]

Emulator screenshot - same behaviour on a Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1

This is the code:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/sign_in_facebook"
                android:width="0dp"
                android:height="0dp"/>
```

Modifying width/height/etc doesn't seem to change anything. Also tried to copy-paste Facebook's example on their docs - no luck.

Here's the activity theme

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>

    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/login_hint</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_dark</item>

    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>

    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material</item>
</style>
```

(@color/primary is orange, @color/text is white)

I am using Facebook Sdk version 4.5.0.

Comment: `<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" /> `

Comment: Same behaviour. Just little width changes. Seems like the button wraps on text but...text is not visible.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fIbYrmP.png?1

Comment: Make sure that `android:text="@string/sign_in_facebook"` is not empty in all your String XML files [en, ....] or text color is not facebook blue :)

Comment: It isn't empty, also tried to hardcode the string directly into layout, no luck. Also setting button text programmatically produces no change at all.

update: and no, text color is not blue. I am also able to change button color to...say, orange, but it doesn't show up anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        />
```

Comment: Same result...
_(Well, actually, not exactly the same. Just a little bit shorter, due to wrap content. But same behaviour - text does not show up)_

Comment: make your custom button with icon and text and apply facebookloginbutton.performClick() inside your custom button click listener  like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32082761/3541465

Comment: Ok, could be a workaround. I'll try it (and probably use it, if no one comes with a better solution), anyway, would be smarter if it worked with its default button.

Comment: the problem with your Facebook login button must be due to the theme but it is difficult to analyse it from here.

Comment: Might be, anyway, I began writing this app today. Really, there's just few theme specs (the one posted above)